# Inca Open Experiment Python

Tags: python, .net, clr, ironpython, python.net

I am working on python and i need to use a Tool named "Inca". Now i am able to run remotely this tool but i can't to open an experiment located in a specific workspace.

```
import sys,clr
sys.path.append("*path*")
clr.AddReference("incacom")

from de.etas.cebra.toolAPI.Inca import*

targetFolder = None
myDB = None
tempItemm = None

a = Inca()

myDB = a.GetCurrentDataBase()

tempItem = myDB.GetItemInFolder("*par1"*, "*par2*")

w = myDB.GetActivehardwareConfiguration()
exp = w.GetAssignedExperimentEnviroment()
e = exp.OpenExperiment()
```

Comment: So whats the errormessage? 
Have you tried writing exp.openExperiment() with only one "n"?

Comment: @AnyOneElse and with a big "O".

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a configuration problem. Either you don't have an active hardware configuration, or an experiment environment wasn't assigned to it. As a result, one of your calls returns `None`, which you don't check for, and the next call fails because `NoneType` doesn't have the method you expect.

Nevertheless, if you know the name of your experiment environment, you can always find it via `BrowseItem` call on your Inca database:

```
a.GetCurrentDataBase().BrowseItem('MyExperiment')[0].OpenExperiment()
```